# How to show a text in only search pages on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, xml, css, blogger

I'm having a problem about showing headdings. I have added search box into my blog, but in homepage there is a text called "Latest News". It is in just homepage and archive pages. But when I search something in my search box, there is still this headding.

I use this code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<h5>Latest News</h5>
</b:if>
```

What can I do to change this text in only search pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to appear exclusively on search results pages (`/search?q={searchQuery}`) use the following code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery != &quot;&quot;'>
<!-- Your content goes here -->
</b:if>
```

In addition you can retreive the search query using the <data:blog.searchQuery/> tag and display something like:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery != &quot;&quot;'>
<h5>Search results for <data:blog.searchQuery/></h5>
</b:if>
```

Joining everything your final code snippet might be something like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
  <h5>Latest News</h5>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.searchQuery != &quot;&quot;'/>
  <h5>Search results for <data:blog.searchQuery/></h5>
<b:else/>
  <h5>[content to display in other cases]</h5>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Be careful. Print `<data:blog.searchQuery/>` and `<data:blog.searchLabel/>` in visible parts of the template turns your site vulnerable to code injection because these tags show your values literally.

Comment: @1e90ff Interesting point. I've tried "searching" literal JS code but nothing weird happened. ¿Can you point how a code injection can be performed in this case? Thanks, I'm not an expert in that area.